# WORD VBA to find highest List Level number of a list

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to find the above for following list. We already know the `ActiveDocument.Lists(1).ListParagraphs.Count` gives number of items in the list:

```
OList = ActiveDocument.Lists(1)
```

For example, is there any WORD VBA property that would return 3 - the highest List Level number - for the following WORD Document lists:

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: Loop over the `ListParagraphs` and get the largest `ListFormat.ListLevelNumber`

Comment: @TimWilliams I added up doing the same. Was hoping if there was some such a property in the `WORD Object Model`. But it seems there is none.